# How to edit a line in a file using node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to update few lines in a file.
Does node.js allow this feature ?

Note: i dont want to create a new file.

I tried looking up on stackoverflow but did not find any suitable solution.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692835/overwrite-a-line-in-a-file-using-node-js

Comment: Thanks.But Isn't there any simple way to do this. As i just have 18 lines in my file and i need to update only 2 of them on each call.

Comment: 18 lines can be held in memory and updated with sync file [read](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options) & [write](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_filename_data_options) calls