# How can I change a specific line in a file with node js?

Tags: node.js, file, fs

I want to change a specific line in a text file using node js with the fs module.

Is there a more elegant way then loading the file into an array?

Old File:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

New File:

```
Line 1
something new
Line 3
```

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11725290/1248388

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overwrite a line in a file using node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692835/overwrite-a-line-in-a-file-using-node-js)

Answer (score 7):

Try using this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile("your file", {encoding: 'utf8'}, function (err,data) {
    var formatted = data.replace(/This is the old line/g, 'This new line replaces the old line');
fs.writeFile("your file", formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
 });
});
```

If this doesn't work, visit  https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file.

Comment: Solution given in another question is also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/30764806/713573