# NodeJS how to write a file in a defined line

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a file with 10 lines of text, I have written a script to add more text, but only the end, I would like to add text in another line, for example in line 5

```
const fs = require('fs');
var comment = "/* \n */"
fs.appendFileSync("jsComents.js", comment, "UTF-8",{'flags': 'w+'});
```

The result in jsComments.js

```
var Food =
['hamburger',
    'pizza',
    'Sandwich',
    'Burritos'
];
var drink = [
'water',
'soda']
/* 
*/
```

I would like to add the comment before the var drink

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert string at line number nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764424/insert-string-at-line-number-nodejs)

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fs = require('fs');
var comment = "/* \n */"

var lineNumber  = 5;
var data = fs.readFileSync('jsComents.js').toString().split("\n");
data.splice(lineNumber, 0, comment);
var text = data.join("\n");

fs.writeFile('jsComents.js', text, function (err) {
if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

It works. the result:

```
var Food =
['hamburger',
    'pizza',
    'Sandwich',
    'Burritos'
];
/* 
*/
var drink = [
'water', 'soda']
```