# Writing at end of every line in a file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, file

I have a file 

`one
two
three`

I want to append a word at the end of every line in this file. How can I achieve that in node ?

eg.

`onecandy
twocandy
threecandy`

Then I want to use this file in another function ,i.e after all`candy` has been added . How do i do that ?

Comment: Can you please show us a snippet of your code of how do you read and write lines?

Comment: it is just a general question. i mean i can read a text line by line and also write text line by line. But the question above has bothered me for some time now .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you will have to read the line to know where is ending and also you have to write at the end of the each line.

In conclusion you have to read everything and write at the end of each line just appending won't save to much performance it only complicate the things.

```
var fs  = require("fs");

var allLines = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt').toString().split('\n');
fs.writeFileSync('./input.txt', '', function(){console.log('file is empty')})
allLines.forEach(function (line) { 
    var newLine = line + "candy";
    console.log(newLine);
    fs.appendFileSync("./input.txt", newLine.toString() + "\n");
});

// each line would have "candy" appended
allLines = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt').toString().split('\n');
```

**Note:** For replacing just some specified lines you can [go through this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692835/overwrite-a-line-in-a-file-using-node-js).

Comment: Yes, it does add candy to each line. But what if I want to execute a function on the whole file after candy has been added !

Comment: @saru95 You read again from the file or you can save the appendings in another array, which one fits you better.

Comment: `\r\n` for Windows' encoding