# NodeJS reading a txt file, read specific line, then edit that line

Tags: node.js, text-files

I have a file, "./uid/total.txt".

I want to read its line "2" which is the total users.

Then use that variable and then add 1 to it and rewrite the "./uid/total.txt"'s line "2" to the new amount.

The code used is:

```
    client.addListener('message#', function (from, to, message) {
        if (message.length < 1 || !(message[0] == '!')) {
            return;
        }
        message = message.slice(1);
        var params = message.split(/\s/);
        var user = from.toLowerCase()
        switch (params[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case 'register':
        get_line('./uid/total.txt', 2, (function(err, totals){
            if (err) {
              client.say(channel, 'error');
              return;
            }
            prevtotuser = totals;
          }));
        client.say(to, User + ' has registed now with a total number of '+totalnum+' users');
        break;
        if (switcher != null) {
          client.say(to, user+', command: !anon <on/off>')
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692835/overwrite-a-line-in-a-file-using-node-js

Comment: I have tried that and it does not seem to work, it takes the read amount and puts the new amount after it (ex: *before: 11* - *after: 1112*)