# Nodejs Edit single row in CSV

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv

I am trying to understand how I would use TypeScript and Nodejs to grab a Csv file by row number and edit that row. I assume the steps would be to 'get line 2, read the single line, save that to an object, I change the data, delete line 2, write a new line 2 with my new object data".

I'm able to read the file and iterate row by row. So I can easily grab the row id. I'm running into a wall trying to figure out the actual editing of a single row, and seems the only way to 'edit' is to delete the row and add it back. I need to add the line back to the exact line number, since I'm iterating row by row and if I just added the new line to the end of the file my script would never stop.

I'm using the `csv-writer` package to write a full Csv file, the `csv-parse` package in conjunction with the `fs.createReadStream()` to iterate row by row of a Csv.

Comment: Are you looking to read/stream all the file and modify every line line-by-line? Or are you looking to have a script which would be occasionally be triggered with the input: line number, new data for that line?

Comment: I currently have a method that returns a Promise based `ReadStream`, and I pass a callback into this method to iterate row by row. It would be nice to build onto this logic.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how write/replace to a specific line. Maybe the following might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692835/overwrite-a-line-in-a-file-using-node-js and https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file. Then using `stringifyRecords` of [csv-writer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer) to generate the new contents of the line.